# Temporary upgrade of IP67 servo motor to IP69K

Tags: servo, waterproofing, seals

I have this IP67 rated servo motor

[image]

and I would like to test it on a device, which undergoes IP69K washdown (once daily high-pressure, hot jet with cleaning agents used in food processing plants). The test will last only 1-3 months and I don't care about damage to the motor or irreversible modifications as long as it lasts utill the end of the test. The connectors and cables are also rated IP67.

What would be a practical method to "upgrade" this system towards IP69K? I'm thinking about an extra sealing layer on the connectors after they are mated and screws tightened up. Perhaps a spray-on or brush-on layer of epoxy? What would you use? Any other areas of concern?

Buying IP69K rated equivalent is not a solution I'm looking for due to excessive cost.

Comment: Build a cover for it so no direct spray